How to prevent LlamaIndex queryengine from reloading LLM on each query?
I'm trying to experiment with LlamaIndex and build up a chatbot answering on provided documents and doing some research I ended up with a code like the following (I've purged out irrelevant parts):
#...

query_engine = None

#...

prompt = ('<system-prompt>')
Settings.embed_model = OllamaEmbedding(model_name="nomic-embed-text")
Settings.llm = Ollama(model="llama3:latest", request_timeout=360.0, system_prompt=prompt, temperature=0.1)
    
#...

storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir="<path-to-stored-index>")
index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context)
query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
    
#...

@app.route('/api/query', methods=['POST'])
def query():
    data = request.json
    user_message = data['query']

    if query_engine is not None:
        response = str(query_engine.query(user_message))
    else:
        response = 'Query engine not initialized' 

    return jsonify({'answer': response})

#...

The service is powered by Flask + Gunicorn to have a persistent agent running in background, waiting for queries (currently with 4 workers).
The problem is that every time I start the systemctl for my service, logging time reveals that the agents go up a little too fast for something that should be loading a model, which might be fine, maybe they prefer to just load it at first use, which they do, since at first query I wait around 15 seconds for an answer, which again can be fine, for the first call.
The problem is that each subsequent call to query doesn't pass again from initialization (so I'm sure that everything outside query function is not executed again), but execution time remains the same, suggesting that the LLM is reloaded every time.
How can I avoid that?
I know that when you run Ollama in CLI, for example, it stays on and the model is not reloaded at each query, so it should be possible to replicate such behaviour, but I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong here.

EDIT

Further information due to further investigations.
I've updated source code adding a little piece on missing information:
Settings.embed_model = OllamaEmbedding(model_name="nomic-embed-text")

So yes, I'm using a model for embedding of course and what I've found out is that when calling query_engine.query it loads the embedding model, does something, then loads the main LLM and answers the query.
The problem is that this way, for each query, models keep being loaded and unloaded because it needs to switch between the embedding model and the LLM.
Shouldn't the embedding operation be done just once when I load my stored indexes?
Why is it doing that every single time?
It that avoidable or is the only solution switching to a payed option like OpenAI?
